# How to create iptables rule to allow IP Address with any sub directory

Tags: iptables, haproxy, lxc

I currently have a DigitalOcean Ubuntu 16.04x64 server with Linux Containers to house multiple sites. One of the containers has HAProxy installed and routes incoming traffic to their appropriate containers. Each container has a unique IP Address given to it upon creation.

I ran the following command to create a rule to the iptables nat table:

*sudo iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -i eth0 -p TCP -d your_server_ip/32 --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination your_haproxy_ip:80*

This works correctly and any domain I have pointed to the server gets redirected to the container its supposed to go to.

I am currently migrating sites from another server and still need the domains pointed there until I have tested the sites on the new server. Also, for future development I would like to access the containers without having a domain name pointed to it yet.

So my question is, how can I edit the above command to create a rule that will allow for sub directories? For example: *159.203.86.144/test* or *159.203.86.144/10.23.98.211*

Comment: You don't. Firewalls don't operate like that.

Answer (score 1):

Agree with **Michael Hampton**, if you want to do it, you should use reverse proxy like `nginx`, it would be better solution. You could read about it in [this article](https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/reverse-proxy/).

Comment: Actually I just tested and figured out that it already is working and pointing to the correct container. The 404 Not Found error is coming from the nginx server within the container. I should be able to get the functionality I need now by setting the directory url within the container correctly. Thanks for the link to the article though, I'm sure it will still be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so it turns out that the original rule that was made could already handle the sub directory path that I needed to reach the container.

> http://server_ip/linux_container_ip

I added this configuration to the frontend of /etc/haproxy/haproxy.conf

> acl host_test url_beg -i /linux_container_ip

And then within the Linux Container, added an alias to /etc/nginx/sites-available/default

```
location /linux_container_ip {
alias /path/to/root/production/folder/here;
}
```